# Error given only in terminal?

Tags: java, oop, error-handling, compiler-errors

I have a rock paper scissors program done, and when I run it in Eclipse it compiles fine and the game plays okay. Although, when I compile it in terminal (using Ubuntu) I get the following error:

> xx@xx:~/Dropbox$ cd T* xx@xxxx:~/Dropbox/xx$ ls
>   RPSGame.java  RPSPlayer.java  RPSTournament.java
>   xx@xx:~/Dropbox/xxxx$ javac RPSTournament error: Class names,
>   'RPSTournament', are only accepted if annotation processing is
>   explicitly requested 1 error xx@choloboy:~/Dropbox/xx$

Any idea what this could mean?

Comment: how are you compiling it? remember it has to be *java RPSTournament.java*

Comment: thats exactly what I put... And I am using eclipse! I am just wanna know why when i use terminal it doesnt compile

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to include the file extension ".java" on the command line when compiling.

To compile use:

> javac RPSTournament.java

To run use:

> java RPSTournament